# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'. Working fine yesterday?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

When I run `from PIL import Image` or `from PIL import Image` etc, I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\Pruthvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

So odd since these same exact commands were working fine yesterday when I was exploring the PIL and pillow modules. (I'm not sure how these two modules are related).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow.

None of the solutions on Reddit/StackOverflow for a similar problem have helped me.

I'm on windows and I'm running the latest versions of python and pillow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution that worked for me.

Using pip to uninstall Pillow.

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

And then using easy_install to reinstall Pillow.

```
easy_install Pillow
```

I hope this helps others.